# Upgrading MySQL on Centos 6.5 using IUS dependency warning

Tags: mysql, centos, updates, yum

I'm trying to replace mysql on my centos server from the default version to the IUS version (I've done it with php and it was success)

The server runs several sites, and virtualmin.

when trying to replace the old mysql with mysql56u I get this warning:

> WARNING: Unable to resolve all providers:
>   ['libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)',
>   'libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)',
>   'libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit)',
>   'libmysqlclient_r.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)',
>   'mysql-libs(x86-64)', 'ha_archive.so.0()(64bit)',
>   'ha_blackhole.so.0()(64bit)', 'ha_example.so.0()(64bit)',
>   'ha_federated.so.0()(64bit)', 'ha_innodb_plugin.so.0()(64bit)']

Should I ignore it or will it break my server ?
Should I try to replace these packages before I go for the mysql upgrade ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, ignoring it worked for me.

Now there is CENTOS 7.0 so it already got the new mysql.